# How to save the if then else output in a variable unix

Tags: bash, unix, datastage

I have a variable(stageVar) getting from  Datastage, and need to check whether that variable is equal to zero then replace the 100 else stageVar.
After that I need to find the mod and save in variable.

I have tried the below code but am not successful.

```
var= if [stageVar -eq 0] ; then "100" ; else stageVar ; fi; var2='expr $var % 100'; echo $var2;
```

Comment: What do you mean "replace the 100 else stageVar"?

Comment: Yes, if stagevar = 0 then var should be 100 if not stageVar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this in bash:

```
[[ $stageVar -eq 0 ]] && var=100 || var=$stageVar
((var2 = var % 100))
echo $var2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `if/then/else` construction, you can use:

```
var=$(if [ "$stageVar" = 0 ]; then echo "100"; else echo $stageVar; fi)
```